# GDB can't find symbol defined in header file of boost BGL

Tags: c++, boost, gdb, inline, symbols

I am able to compile and run an executable that uses C++ boost graph library (BGL) on OSX 10.8.3.
But when I try to debug using either gdb or Xcode the debugger is unable to find symbols defined in the BGL header file `adjacency_list.hpp`.
I looked at the file and tried different namespaces

```
boost::in_degree 
boost::detail::in_degree
```

But debuggers could not find symbols.
It seems the function is inlined and the information is lost.
I tried another function (add_vertex) with same result.
I compile the code using CMake with the flag `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and I am able to print other symbols.
Please suggest how can I fix this.

```
// Trying using 
(gdb) print boost::detail::in_degree
    No symbol "in_degree" in namespace "boost::detail".
(gdb) print boost::detail::in_degree(0, *pGraph)
    No symbol "in_degree" in namespace "boost::detail".
(gdb) print boost::in_degree(0, *pGraph)
    No symbol "in_degree" in namespace "boost".

// Trying using boost::
(gdb) pt boost::in_degree
    No symbol "in_degree" in namespace "boost".
(gdb) pt boost::in_degree(0, *pGraph)
    No symbol "in_degree" in namespace "boost".
```

Comment: Which version of the BGL are you using? I tried 1.37, 1.46, 1.52 and haven't seen a `in_degree` in `adjacency_list.hpp` with your definition.

Comment: @PatrickB. It is in boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp.

Comment: @PartickB I am using boost 1.53. The `in_degree` is there in the `adjacency_list.hpp`. Its the debuggers (gdb and Xcode) that can't find the symbols. I tried `nm` on my compiled library that uses `in_degree` and it shows the symbol for `in_degree`.